# /bin/sh: parsing command line arguments results in: shift: can't shift that many

Tags: shell, sh, command-line-arguments, getopts

I need to parse command line arguments myself, not rely on `getopt` or other function.

My script (simplified below) takes optional parameter `-P` followed by a pattern, and then a filename:

```
./myscript -P "pattern" file.txt
```

The command line arguments can be in any order, `./myscript file.txt -P "pattern"` is allowed. But `-P` must always be followed by pattern.

The problem that I am facing is, when `-P` was provided, I need to "eat" the next argument, so that it is not interpreted as file name. So I use `shift`. But it seems the `for` loop already has the original `$@` array read in, so that even when I shift, it still iterates over "pattern", and interprets it as file.

So instead  of 2 iterations of the for cycle, I have 3:

```
# 1. cycle:
arg = -P
$@ = -P pattern file
pattern =
file =

# 2. cycle:
arg = pattern
$@ = file
pattern = pattern
file =

3. cycle    
arg = file
$@ =
pattern = pattern
file = pattern
```

My expectation was, the for loop was supposed to be run twice: for `-P` and for `file`. Instead, it is run 3 times, and I get this error:

```
shift: can't shift that many
```

How can I solve this?

```
#!/bin/sh

f=
pattern=

 for arg do

    echo arg = $arg
    echo \$\@ = $@
    echo pattern = $pattern
    echo file = $f
    echo

    shift

    case "$arg" in

    (-P)
        if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
            pattern="$1"
            shift
        else
            printf "\nError: -P needs an argument\n\n" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;

    (*)
        if [ -z "$f" ] ; then
            f="$arg"
        else
            printf "\nError: too many arguments: $f $arg\n\n" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;

    esac
 done
```

Comment: what is the value of arg? you don't seem to set it anywhere

Comment: I guess this is because you have already run out of args to be shifted.

Comment: @joshmeranda - that is standard way to process command line arguments. By default, if no list is specified, `for arg do` goes through `$@`.

Comment: Oh neat hadn't seen that before. Here's the excerpt from the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) if anyone wants it : "If ‘in words’ is not present, the for command executes the commands once for each positional parameter that is set, as if ‘in "$@"’ had been specified".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop keeps its own private copy of the positional parameter list that you can't alter using `shift` or `set` (see [Modifying positional parameters while iterating over them in POSIX sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099135/modifying-positional-parameters-while-iterating-over-them-in-posix-sh)).

Use a while loop instead.

```
parse_args()
  while test $# -gt 0; do
    case $1 in
    (-P)
      p=$2
      shift ;;
    (*)
      f=$1
    esac
    shift
  done

p= f=
parse_args "$@"
```